# data.table: performance of binary search VS vector scan

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I was looking at the best way to subset on a data.table defined as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(2L)
N = 1e7L
DT = data.table(x = sample(letters, N, TRUE),
                y = sample(1000L, N, TRUE),
                val = runif(N))
setkey(DT, x, y)
```

There is the binary search (SUBSET1) and also the 'vector scan way' (SUBSET2).

```
SUBSET1 <- function(){
  a <- DT[.(c("a"), c(5L)), .N, nomatch = NULL]
}
SUBSET2 <- function(){
  a <- DT[ x == "a" & y == 5L, .N, nomatch = NULL]
}
```

What I quite like with the 'vector scan way' is that it is really self-explanatory and very readable. Nevertheless, it seems to be 2 times slower compared to the native binary search way.

```
microbenchmark(SUBSET1(), 
               SUBSET2(), 
               times = 500 )
  Unit: milliseconds
        expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq      max neval
   SUBSET1() 1.0328 1.27790 1.878415 1.53370 1.8924  20.5789   500
   SUBSET2() 2.4896 3.06665 4.476864 3.52685 4.3682 179.1607   500
```

**My question**
I don't understand why SUBSET2 is slower. Is it because there is a kind of internal conversion from 'vector scan way' to binary search or because 'vector scan way' is executed as such (and thus slower than binary search)?

Comment: Use `verbose=TRUE`, your vector scan might be already optimized under the hood to binary search. Timings in milliseconds won't be that much relevant because all orchestration of the query takes some time, so the smaller the units, the less useful conclusion about binary search vs vector scan. It is much more useful to benchmark "bigger picture" of your workflow. My answer would be, it slower because of the orchestration costs and "milliseconds".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As pointed out by @jangorecki, both queries are already using the key -- the latter one just takes a small amount of extra time to map the "vector scan" form into the binary search form. You can see this with `verbose=TRUE`:

```
DT[ x == "a" & y == 5L, .N, nomatch = NULL, verbose = TRUE]
```

shows output:

```
Optimized subsetting with key 'x, y'
forder.c received 1 rows and 2 columns
forder took 0.001 sec
x is already ordered by these columns, no need to call reorder
i.x has same type (character) as x.x. No coercion needed.
i.y has same type (integer) as x.y. No coercion needed.
on= matches existing key, using key
Starting bmerge ...
bmerge done in 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
Constructing irows for '!byjoin || nqbyjoin' ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
Detected that j uses these columns: <none>
```

Compare with the direct binary search version:

```
DT[.("a", 5L), .N, nomatch = NULL, verbose = TRUE]
```

```
i.V1 has same type (character) as x.x. No coercion needed.
i.V2 has same type (integer) as x.y. No coercion needed.
on= matches existing key, using key
Starting bmerge ...
forder.c received 1 rows and 2 columns
bmerge done in 0.001s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
Constructing irows for '!byjoin || nqbyjoin' ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
Detected that j uses these columns: <none>
```

But that's half as slow right? Also as pointed out, the time scale is very small. A more useful comparison is vs. the case when no key is used at all. Let's make an unsorted copy of your data:

```
DTrand = DT[sample(.N)]
```

Another quick aside -- we have to be careful for benchmarking because `data.table` is also doing some automatic optimizations to help sort your data even in this unsorted case:

```
DTrand[ x == "a" & y == 5L, .N, nomatch = NULL, verbose = TRUE]
```

Read the output carefully:

```
Creating new index 'y__x'
Creating index y__x done in ... forder.c received 10000000 rows and 3 columns
forder took 0.424 sec
0.286s elapsed (1.117s cpu) 
Optimized subsetting with index 'y__x'
forder.c received 1 rows and 2 columns
forder took 0.002 sec
x is already ordered by these columns, no need to call reorder
i.y has same type (integer) as x.y. No coercion needed.
i.x has same type (character) as x.x. No coercion needed.
on= matches existing index, using index
Starting bmerge ...
bmerge done in 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
Constructing irows for '!byjoin || nqbyjoin' ... 0.000s elapsed (0.001s cpu) 
Reorder irows for 'mult=="all" && !allGrp1' ... forder.c received 360 rows and 2 columns
0.000s elapsed (0.002s cpu) 
Detected that j uses these columns: <none> 
[1] 360
```

`data.table` has automatically applied `setindex` to your table, which (while not as fast as physical sorting like with `setkey`), will nevertheless speed up any future subsets; simply repeating (as would happen with a benchmark):

```
DTrand[ x == "a" & y == 5L, .N, nomatch = NULL, verbose = TRUE]
```

Notice the similarity vs the keyed case (swap `key` for `index`):

```
Optimized subsetting with index 'y__x'
forder.c received 1 rows and 2 columns
forder took 0 sec
x is already ordered by these columns, no need to call reorder
i.y has same type (integer) as x.y. No coercion needed.
i.x has same type (character) as x.x. No coercion needed.
on= matches existing index, using index
Starting bmerge ...
bmerge done in 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
Constructing irows for '!byjoin || nqbyjoin' ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
Reorder irows for 'mult=="all" && !allGrp1' ... forder.c received 360 rows and 2 columns
0.001s elapsed (0.001s cpu) 
Detected that j uses these columns: <none> 
[1] 360
```

Thus, a naive benchmark even on `DTrand` wouldn't be a true comparison -- after the first benchmark run, the table will be indexed and subsequent subsets will use this & binary search. See [the vignette on secondary indices](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html) for more details.

We can sidestep this and get a proper benchmark by setting the option `datatable.auto.index` to `FALSE` and resetting the existing index:

```
options(datatable.auto.index = FALSE)
setindex(DTrand, NULL)
```

Now `data.table` forgets how to sort `DTrand` by `x` and `y` and we can compare the binary search approach and true vector subsetting:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  times = 50L,
  vector = DTrand[ x == "a" & y == 5L, .N, nomatch = NULL],
  binary = DT[     x == "a" & y == 5L, .N, nomatch = NULL]
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min         lq       mean     median        uq        max neval
#  vector 101.43306 114.325340 134.154362 119.367909 128.05273 345.721296    50
#  binary   1.06033   1.160188   1.631119   1.367017   1.57334   5.508802    50
```

So while the straight-up approach using `.()` is twice as fast as the optimized approach using `==`, `==` is still 100x faster than a *true* vector subset.

You might also benefit from the [`data.table` benchmarking vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-benchmarking.html)